# IIS 7.5 firefox "XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: Line Number 1, Column 1:"

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

Running to a dead end i have a page that works fine on IIS 7 however on IIS 7.5 it gives me an error

The page does a redirect if the search term matches a term in the database if nothing match the page is empty.

called redirect.aspx

and this only happens on firefox

on IIS 7.0 it just comes up as a blank page however on IIS it gives a error.

I think i got a solution however not sure how to do it.

when comparing IIS 7.5 and 7.0 content-type is set to text-html on 7.5 its gives

"XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: http://***/redirect.aspx?term=bikes Line Number 1, Column 1:"

any idea how to fix this thank you in advance.